Microsoft Teams bot responding 401 Unauthorized
I am working on Teams bot using .NET bot sdk (Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.18.1) & I am getting 401 unauthorized error. could not figure out why here is my request data
POST /api/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44394
User-Agent: Microsoft-SkypeBotApi (Microsoft-BotFramework/3.0)
Content-Length: 992
Authorization: Bearer [REMOVED]
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Ms-Cv: 7EWW5IRJZkWRtCwWEmPpkw.2.1
X-Forwarded-For: 52.114.32.186
X-Forwarded-Host: zzzdev.ngrok.io
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Ms-Conversation-Id: a:1x85PXDsYewtyUQRS_us2DInv_qqgwYShfO4tL9lEPQ4CNNakapZLHNOQls1F429fXNzTULjuwbTiXlHLGDX_Mr90kwub51TbmDMuBQENsagL1fUPgyR-Nag1jC1a5Omt
X-Ms-Tenant-Id: 70ec66fa-6661-41f6-863b-98c2c1461111
Accept-Encoding: gzip   



{
  "action": "add",
  "type": "installationUpdate",
  "timestamp": "2024-04-26T15:07:45.545Z",
  "id": "f:b89617c7-7a3d-345a-d9f7-64248c54eaA2",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1dwK1j6nlDTyoaOzbCWwbPZnkqTayufAmLGICeQvN5o46o5xAAuhqnHajqFUW-H209IvzWI_uYF3A6xNmlFUPQD",
    "aadObjectId": "[REMOVED]"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "tenantId": "70ec66fa-6661-41f6-863b-98c2c1461111",
    "id": "a:1x85PXDsYewtyUQRS_us2DInv_qqgwYShfO4tL9lEPQ4CNNakapZLHNOQls1F429fXNzTULjuwbTiXlHLGDX_Mr90kwub51TbmDMuBQENsagL1fUPgyR-Nag1jC1a5Omt"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "28:022a667a-c3c0-4743-bc7d-326165eaa1c4",
    "name": "DEV1-BOT-HANDLE"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "en-US",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "settings": {
      "selectedChannel": {
        "id": "19:[REMOVED]"
      }
    },
    "tenant": {
      "id": "70ec66fa-6661-41f6-863b-98c2c1461111"
    },
    "source": {
      "name": "message"
    }
  },
  "locale": "en-US"
}

what can be the reason for this ? and I see this error too in azure 

Check App Id and Password
